# Is there a social plugin to post on walls/tweet directly to a person?

Tags: twitter, facebook-social-plugins

Is there currently a social plugin or a way to post directly to someone's wall or tweet directly at someone?

For example, say I have a list of people on my page:

1. Nicholas Cage
2. Robin Williams
3. Kiss
4. Pink

Is there a way to post to their wall/tweet without leaving my page? I currently have it set that it opens their page in a new window, but it would be much more usable to be able to do it this way.

Comment: The Feed dialog allows you to specify the id of the wall the post should go to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 1):

You could do that in the background from the server, but if the social site asks for a confirmation, you'll have to go back to the user again. As all top social sites ask for confirmation you would only catch users who confirmed before... If this is worth the effort is up to you.